# How to know all the SVN commits done under my login

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

am using Tortoise SVN from few months. I just want to track down what are the files i had committed to svn till date. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on TortoiseSVN you can do a repo-browser and click on the root of your repository than right mouse button -> Show Log -> click "Show All" and fill in your user name in the top-line of Tortoise and furthermore you can limit the view based on a date as well ..or you can use a tool as described before (statsvn..)...

Answer (score 2):

This application can give you good statistics for your svn repo.

http://www.statsvn.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `svn log -q -v` and extract files from revisions under your name. Example of output

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r24 | lazybadger | 2010-07-17 06:10:18 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Hello.de.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.en.txt
   M /trunk/Hello.fr.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```